# How to display the Current Temp of the visible cities on the Leaflet map using OpenweathweatherMap?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, openweathermap

I am trying to display the Temperature of multiple cities dynamically on a leaflet map as shown in the image below.

[image: What I want to achieve]

Here's my code and it's outcome:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import L from "leaflet";
import "../MainContent/MergeStyles.css";
import "./Map.css";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

import {
  MapContainer,
  TileLayer,
  useMap,
  Marker,
  Popup,
  Tooltip,
} from "react-leaflet";

function Map(props) {
  let location = props.location;
  let weatherData = props.weatherData;
  const markerIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl:
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Location_dot_black.svg/768px-Location_dot_black.svg.png",
    iconSize: [7, 7],
  });

  let { lat, lon } = location[0];

  // let loc = { lat, lon };
  console.log(lat, lon);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="map leaflet-container sidebar-open default-styles">
        <MapContainer
          center={[lat, lon]}
          zoom={10}
          zoomControl={false}
          scrollWheelZoom={true}
        >
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          <Marker position={[lat, lon]} icon={markerIcon}>
            <Tooltip
              className="tooltip"
              direction="right"
              opacity={1}
              permanent
            >
              <div className="tooltip-div">
                <p className="temp-tooltip">{weatherData.current.temp}&deg;C</p>
              </div>
            </Tooltip>
            <Popup>
              A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
);
}

export default Map;
```

[image]

NOTE: I've updated the code a bit and displayed the current temperature of the given location, but I want to display the surrounding cities' Temperature too.

Comment: Here you have only an empty map, you haven't even tried to fetch any data or to visualize them

Comment: I have access to weather data and can show the current city data on the map, but can't figure out how to show data of multiple cities dynamically

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data you have

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've updated the code a bit. will wait for your response. thank you

Comment: You need to provide also the a sample of your data you have otherwise I cannot help  you. It seems you get the data from props

Comment: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=34.025917&lon=71.560135&units=metric&appid=c92c71b636845f60f631c6c9d55bb023

Comment: I provide the link to the exact data I am getting from API. On every search query on homepage, the API is being called and I pass the particular data (weatherData, coords) to the Map Component as props. I'm sure you now understand the whole scenario